# Can i Union 3 ToSelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have three seperate ToSelectList items and i wanted to combine each list into one dropdown list box and was wondering if i could use a Union for it. Or is it that a union is only for 2 toselectlist items only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When item exists in more than one list, do you want item to appear once, or as many times as they exists in all lists?

As I understand you want just concat:

```
var combinedList = list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3).ToList();
```

If you want to avoid duplicates:

```
var unionList = list1.Union(list2).Union(list3).ToList();
```

Union is more expensive, as it has to go through the list and take care of duplicates.
If your item is a reference type and there is no IComparable or IEquable interfaces and you don't provide IEqualityComparer, you likely don't need Union.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, as for what i am doing, the list i have will not have any duplicates because i take care of that in a different part of the application. But if i wanted to add the lists and after each list is there a way to add an empty line so i can tell when a list starts and ends.

Comment: @Amina - Seems like my detailed answer wasn't appreciated.

Comment: Actually it was very appreciated :) and learned two new facts to be honest i guess i was over excited about the results i didn't show my appreciation as i intended.

Comment: @Amina - Ok. Here is suggestion for adding empty line. I don't know what the type of elements in your list, so I assume simple `string`. You can add one line like `list1.Add("----------")` to each list before concatenating. You will need to make sure you handle it correctly when user selects this 'separator' item from the dropdown.

Comment: Here is how i have my lists: 

IQueryable<Store> stores= _storeRepository.FindAllActiveForUser(_currentUser.Name).OrderBy(o=>o.StoreName);
            var storeList =stores.ToSelectList("StoreId", "StoreName", viewModel.StoreId.ToString());

Then i have this for two other lists and then i concat them into one list

Comment: Complete hack, but this is might be what you need:var storeList = _storeRepository.FindAllActiveForUser(_currentUser.Name).OrderBy(o => o.StoreName)­.ToList();
            storeList.Add(new Store { StoreId = -1, StoreName = "-------------" });
            var storeSelectList = storeList.ToSelectList("StoreId", "StoreName", viewModel.StoreId.ToString());

Comment: Thanks! I will use it temporarily and see how it tests out. Also i wanted to know if i wanted to know the id of what the user selected from the dropdown list how can i get that since i concat three different lists and each list has its own results?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [`Union()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) linq extension method.

```
var finalSelectList = model.getFirstList().ToSelectList().Union(
                model.getSecondList().ToSelectList().Union(
                model.getThirdList().ToSelectList()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only union two lists at a time using `Union()` - but you can chain it to achieve what you want:

```
var resultList = list1.Union(list2).Union(list3).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! this takes care of it.

Comment: Concat is much more efficient in this case. How come Union is the answer? :)

Comment: I guess because in my mind union first came to mind but after discussing it i realize concat sounds more direct in the use i want it for.